# Downloading file from another website in PHP creates the file but doesn't download any bytes

Tags: php, file, download

I'm trying to download [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pdg8bnpmbgvcsmd/QR-Kodite.rar) from `DropBox`, i tried the same code with a file on the same website that running the `PHP` script and it did work but now when i add a full `ULR`, it doesn't.

The problem is that the `QR-Kodite.rar` file is created in my `Windows` downloads folder but its size is `0` and `Chrome` says that the download has finished.

**This is my code :**

```
if(isset($_GET['App'])){
    if(basename($_GET['App']) == $_GET['App']){
        $path = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pdg8bnpmbgvcsmd/QR-Kodite.rar';

        $size = filesize($path);
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $path);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        ob_clean(); 

        $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
        if($file){
            fpassthru($file);
            $_SESSION["ITA"] = "No";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check if the size you are getting here `$size = filesize($path);` is correct?

Comment: @EmilioBorraz ,  If i tried to echo the `$size` variable, it will give me an error saying "`Warning: filesize(): stat failed for https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qiqc22osqt2hcg3/STOPit.rar on line 27`"